# Require Pull Request in TFS

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015

Pull Requests were recently implemented in TFS. Is there a way to force users to make Pull Requests, and have others review it before they can merge into a branch?

I've tried restricting Contribute permissions to the branch for a TFS group, but that prevented them from merging through Pull Requests too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You tagged your question with TFS 2013, and I think that what you strictly ask for is not possible.

But in TFS 2015 and [VSO](https://www.visualstudio.com/) you can access a feature called Branch Policies under the team project settings -> Version Control -> Click your Repository -> Branch Policies.

Well there you tick *Require a minimum number of reviewers per pull request*. If it is important that other make the review, make sure that *Allow users to approve their own changes* is not checked.

I have written a [blog post](http://blog.nethouse.se/2015/07/26/pull-requests-in-tfs-2015/) which describes it in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature in TFS 2015 that will support this (it is not in CTP1 that was just released).

Comment: What feature is it?

Comment: It's called branch policies: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/branch-policies

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this by creating 2 separate groups: Approvers and Contributors.  I then restricted the contributors from contributing to a specific branch and only allowed the approvers.

The key difference is that the approvers aren't in the contributors and vice-versa.

If people are in both groups, I would suggest giving the approvers a secondary account until TFS 2015 is available.  This doesn't keep the approvers from pushing changes without a pull request, but at least this gets you in the right direction.